# How to filter none UTF8 chars from a NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring, utf8-decode

I got a String.And I need to convert this string to a NSString using UTF8 encoding . But the origin String may contain none utf8 chars.How to filter this utf8 chars?

Comment: I tried xml = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.c_str()]; method.But I got a nil result.

Comment: You need to figure out what the original encoding of the byte buffer (which isn't really a string until it's decoded) is. From where did you get it?

Comment: It is a UTF8 string with some none UTF8 chars in the middle